# Does Amazon MWS let to pull sales information?

Tags: invoice, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

I have a question about Amazon MWS. Imagine a company sells 100 products in a day and needs to print invoices for them. Is it possible to pull sales data (address, date, price etc) from Amazon to a web application (maybe hourly) and place this data on invoice templates and print them?

Comment: Grammar and capitalisation

Comment: Grammar and capitalisation

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Orders API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/187-5007837-0459543?ie=UTF8&group=orders&section=orders&version=latest)

They have several client libraries to choose from.  You'd need to write software to pull sales data down from Amazon using the Orders API, and then create an invoice with the data however you like.

Comment: @ScoottG how one can generate invoice and label for any order for orderProcessing , is there any API provided from Amazon so that seller can generate label or invoices.Thanks in advance